# Deleting files from windows partition using linux, why are they permanently lost?

Tags: linux, windows

I have a dualbooted pc, windows 7, and debian distro, i mount some windows directories to linux.

I deleted some file from a folder on the windows partition, but i can't find it in the trash. Will i find it in windows trash?

Linux says they are permanently lost and i wonder why?

Comment: Did you use the command line to delete the files, or the GUI?

Comment: Only Windows knows how to handle its `Recycle Bin` if you deleted a file off an external drive in Windows it also wouldn't place it in the `Recycle Bin`.

Comment: @Kruug I used the delete key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are lost because you deleted them.

Basically, when you delete them in windows then windows does the following:

- Permission check (are you allowed to delete them?).
- Check if they should be deleted or should be moved to a drives trashcan. E.g. see the tick [do not move files to the recycle bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXKZz.png) or the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> option.

  - If they should be deleted -> Delete.
  - If moved to trash, make room if needed, then move them there.
  - If moved to trash but larger then trashcan max size: Raise a popup.

On linux it would go like this:

- On Permission check (are you allowed to delete them?).
- Delete files. Soyonara. File is wiped.

TL:DR: the normal `rm` command will not check if there is a windows trashcan and what the windows configuration of that trashcan folder is.

---

[Edit] Some linux distributions might use something similar to the windows trashcan. However that does not mean that they will move files to the windows trashcan. Rather they will use their own. As will windows (with windows not moving it a a specific linux desktops trashcan).

Also, I should have it 'Recycle Bin' rather than trashcan.

Comment: I don't use it everyday but Solaris has general idea of a trashbin folder.  Granted one has to send files to the trashbin specifically otherwise the file is simply deleted.

Comment: I didn't use `rm` i used the delete key and crunchbang has a trashcan

Comment: The Thunar filemanager (which is included in crunchbang) indeed uses a trashcan. It can store deleted stuff in files such as `.Trash-1000`. It will not try to store it in the Recycle bin and thus files should not show up there when you boot windows. For more details we would need to know how your linux side is configured.

Comment: @Hennes what do you need to know exactly? I'll post it here